# Displaying Multiple Images Side by Side With Differing Dimensions in One Window using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm following [the following tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-display-multiple-images-in-one-window-using-opencv-python/) to display two images side by side. [It works just fine when both images share the same dimensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs5yBvv55uI). However, when I try to display two images side by side that have different dimensions, this method fails. I saw it mentioned in [this thread](https://answers.opencv.org/question/175912/how-to-display-multiple-images-in-one-window/) that the method showing in the first tutorial won't work as the image matrices have different dimensions.

How would I go about concatenating two images whose dimensions vary in order to display it using cv2?

Comment: affine transform. define output size. then formulate an affine transform for each picture that scales and translates the picture to be in the middle of its area. apply, then stack. would you like an answer for this? then I'd like two random pictures to demonstrate with.

Comment: Create a black canvas with width equal to the sum of the widths of the two images and height the same as the taller of the two images. Paste your two images onto it and display that.